# Parse a HTML table using Ruby, Nokogiri omitting the column headers

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have trouble parsing a HTML table using Nokogiri and Ruby. My HTML table structure looks like this

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Firstname</td>
       <td>Lastname</td>
       <td>Middle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>ding</td>
       <td>dong</td>
       <td>ling</td>
    </tr>
    ....
    ....
    .... {more tr's and td's with similar data exists.}
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....       
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

In the above HTML table I would like to entirely remove the first  and corresponding  elements, so remove Firstname, Lastname and Middle i.e., I want to start stripping the text only from the second . So this way I get only the contents of the table from the second  or tr[2] and no column headers.

Can someone please provide me a code as to how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Define "stripping the text". What exactly do you want as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(x)
rows = doc.xpath('//table/tbody/tr[position() > 1]')

# OR

rows = doc.xpath("//table/tbody/tr")
header = rows.shift
```

After you've run either one of the above 2 snippets, `rows` will contain every `<tr>...</tr>` after the first one. For example `puts rows.to_xml` prints the following:

```
<tr><td>ding</td>
       <td>dong</td>
       <td>ling</td>
    </tr>
```

To get the inner text, removing all the html tags, run `puts rows.text`

```
ding
       dong
       ling
```

To get the inner text of the td tags only, run `rows.xpath('td').map {|td| td.text }`

```
["ding", "dong", "ling"]
```

Comment: are you sure if this will give me the text from the second tr[2]. I don't want to convert it into an xml. I just want the text from the HTML starting from the second tr[2].

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the explanation. I modified the code snippet a bit and did this. It works for me. rows.xpath('td').map(&:text)[0,3]. I have one more request that I need help with. How do I do this. I have a $ symbol in the beginning of each value in the second and third columns of the table. How do I strip just the dollar symbol and still extract the text from all the 3 columns. So I get ["ding" "$10000" "$0.4567"]. A $symbol is added cause they are a dollar value. So I'd like to strip just the dollar symbol and still get the text from the td's. Can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
table.css('tr')[1..-1]
```

or to strip out the text starting at row 2:

```
table.css('tr')[1..-1].map{|tr| tr.css('td').map &:text}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Nokogiri does support [**:has** CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:has) you can get heading row with

```
@doc.at_css('table#table_id').css('tr:has(th)')
```

and since it does supports **:not** CSS pseudo-class as well, you can get other rows with

```
@doc.at_css('table#table_id').css('tr:not(:has(th))')
```

respectively. Depending on your preferences you might like to avoid negation and just use `css('tr:has(td)')`.